# Unable to unblock project-wide SSH keys for GCP instances

Tags: centos7, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to use project-wide SSH keys on my instances in GCP. However, in the VM instance details, despite unchecking the "Block project-wide SSH keys" checkbox and clicking Save, as advised [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys?hl=en_US&_ga=2.222199633.-873478133.1563284635&_gac=1.182644564.1563284635.CjwKCAjw67XpBRBqEiwA5RCocadAyYYgE1EgJF6z6BOucoqgDMGuUYstN2fzPpegA0CjZbW8RVL39BoCckQQAvD_BwE#block-project-keys), it remains checked and I cannot login to the instances using the SSH keys defined in the project metadata. 
Has anyone else had this problem and managed to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unblock project-wide SSH keys by running this [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys?hl=en_US&_ga=2.222199633.-873478133.1563284635&_gac=1.182644564.1563284635.CjwKCAjw67XpBRBqEiwA5RCocadAyYYgE1EgJF6z6BOucoqgDMGuUYstN2fzPpegA0CjZbW8RVL39BoCckQQAvD_BwE#block-project-keys) command from the cloud shell:

gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME] --metadata block-project-ssh-keys=FALSE

After you run the command you can check if the configuration was applied by running:

gcloud compute instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME] --zone [INSTANCE_ZONE]

Comment: Shouldn't it be --metadata block-project-ssh-keys=FALSE ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be FALSE instead of TRUE

Comment: Remember to edit the answer. Comments are only temporary, and some people do not see them anyway. I have done it for you this time.